Show that $m\ge 1$ $P_{i}(X_n=j \text{ for atleast distinct m integers n})=f_{ij}(f_{ji})^{m-1}$

Define $f_{ij}^{(n)}=P_i(X_n=j,X_t\ne j, 1\le t\le n)$ and $f_{ij}=\sum f_{ij}^{(n)}$
Show that $m\ge 1$ $P_{i}(X_n=j \text{ for atleast distinct m integers n})=f_{ij}(f_{ji})^{m-1}$

Can I get a formal proof of this? I did get an semi formal proof. We know $f_{ij}=P_i(X_n=j \text{ for atleast distinct 1 integer})$. So let $A$ be an event in which at least $2$ time, it is $j$. Then say at time $t_i$ is the ith time $j$ occurs.
So we have $$X_0=i,X_{t_1}=j,X_{t_2}=j,\dots$$
Computing probability, going from $X_0=i$ to $X_{t_1}=j$ is $f_{ij}$ and then $m-1$ times $j \rightarrow j$.
Hence $f_{ij}(f_{ji})^{m-1}$.
But any formal proof for this?
